# Select Data Works fine but, Cannot Insert Data, No errors shown

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am an amateur in C# but I tried to connect to SQL database in C# and I am using Visual Studio 2015.

**Trying to Insert on button click:**

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string hello = "Hello";
    //insert data to database.
    int rows;
    string query = "INSERT INTO MyTable (name) VALUES (@username)";
    try
    {
        using (myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection))
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", hello);
            rows =  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("ROWS AFFECTED: " + rows);
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

The table has only two columns: `ID`(`AUTO_INCREMENT`) and `name`(`nchar(10)`)

Here is what I have tried:
On button click, it shows:

> Rows AFFECTED: 1

Which means there is no exception caught but When I click on "Show Table Data", the table is empty and it doesn't add a new record.

The Insert query works fine when I run it manually using query script.

The connection to the database is fine also as the `SELECT` query runs perfectly fine.

Comment: Where are you clicking "Show Table Data"?  Inside SSMS somewhere or is that a button in your app?

Comment: @Kalmino here: [link](http://s33.postimg.org/drvaewg7z/showtable.jpg)

Comment: @S.Akbari Just tried to change the database option "Copy to output directory" to "Copy if newer" but still insert doesnt work.

Comment: @Mark... Did you used `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\yourDB.mdf` in your `ConnectionString`?

Comment: @S.Akbari Yes I did

Comment: I guess your connection string may be pointed somewhere else.  You could run a select in your code using the same connection immediately after the insert.

Comment: @Mark...So I'm pretty sure that one of the option from duplicate answer should solve your issue. Please read that answer carefully and try all options for example: the databse that is updated is located in the subfolder **BIN\DEBUG** folder of your project. If you want to see the updated data just attach the database located in the bin/debug folder in ssms.  Also make sure your table in server explorer is not already open, if it is already open you must refresh it to show updated data

Comment: @JaredStroeb I am using the same connectionString variable for both queries (SELECT and INSERT) works fine for SELECT but doesnt work for INSERT.

Comment: @S.Akbari Thankyou,  sorry this may be a stupid question, how can I check if my VS2015 has SSMS installed already or do I have to install it seperately?

Comment: @Mark...You could attach the database located in Bin\Debug in server explorer in VS.

Comment: @S.Akbari Thankyou got it now. So how to apply all the changes of BIN/DEBUG database to my actual database file?